# How to search for a particular 2x2 matrix in a 5x2x2 NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, search, indexing

I have a NumPy array of dimension (5,2,2) that is meant to be a series of 2-by-2 matrices. How can I ask and if one of those 2-by-2 matrices has a particular value?

For example, let's take the series below

```
import numpy as np
zeros = np.zeros(4).reshape(2,2)
serie = np.array([zeros+1, zeros+2, zeros+3, zeros+4, zeros+5])
```

Then, there is a 2-by-2 matrix filled with 2s in `serie`. How can I ask if `serie` contains a 2-by-2 matrix filled with 2s and retrieve its index? In this case, the index would be 1 since `serie[1,:]` is the sought matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using simple array comparison, [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html), and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
import numpy as np

zeros = np.zeros(4).reshape(2,2)
serie = np.array([zeros+1, zeros+2, zeros+3, zeros+4, zeros+5])

to_find = zeros+2

index = np.where(np.all(serie == to_find, axis=(1, 2)))[0]
print(index)
```

Output:

```
[1]
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```